sympy.solve never returns for certain coefficients
The form of the expression (corresponding the the variable called 'expression' below) whose critical points I'm trying to solve for is identical in all cases since the only thing that is changing between success and failure is the values of the exponents on each term.
Here is a minimum reproducible example:
from sympy import symbols, Mul, diff, solve
from decimal import Decimal


class Histogram:
    def __init__(self, bins, pdf):
        self.bins = bins
        self.pdf = pdf


histogram = Histogram(
    bins=[-1, 0, 1],
    pdf=[Decimal('0.454861111111111104943205418749130330979824066162109375'),
         Decimal('0'),
         Decimal('0.545138888888888839545643349993042647838592529296875')]
)


def computation(histogram):

    A = Decimal('1')
    e = Decimal('1')
    M_factor = Decimal('1.0828567056280801')
    x = symbols('x')
    product_terms = []
    profit = lambda cp: (e * M_factor ** cp - e) * x
    commission = lambda cp: (e * M_factor ** cp + e) * Decimal('0.0005') * x

    for candles_profit, freq in zip(histogram.bins, histogram.pdf):
        profit_term = profit(candles_profit)
        commission_term = commission(candles_profit)
        term = ((A + profit_term - commission_term) / A) ** freq
        product_terms.append(term)

    expression = Mul(*product_terms)
    derivative = diff(expression, x)
    solutions = solve(derivative, x)
    print("Solutions:", solutions)


computation(histogram)

The 'expression' variable in the computation function above turns into the following in the debugger:
(1.0 - 0.0774785191289289x)^0.454861111111111 \* (0.0818152772752661x + 1.0)^0.545138888888889

If you create a python file with the example above and run it, it never returns when attempting to find the expression's critical points.
The unique feature I see that may explain the failure is that it has repeating decimals in its exponents, like a rational number like 2/3. To confirm my intuition that this is the source of the error, I revisited the trades that formed the histogram for this symbol: 131 were in the -1 bucket and 157 were in the +1 bucket. 131/288 = 0.454861 with a repeating 1, and 157/288 = 0.545138 with a repeating 8. So it appears that even though the Decimal values keep many places of precision in the histogram we pass in to the computation function, those values are inaccurate since the repetition ceases after a while, but even that doesn't matter because sympy cuts the values off before that point. Since sympy.solve coerces my input python Decimals into sympy Floats, not sympy Rationals, is it reasonable to expect that this is the source of the issue? If yes, how could I modify my code to allow the computation to resolve properly instead of getting stuck forever?

A "minimal" example would be about three lines of code. There are several options here but most likely you should use nsolve rather than solve.

@OscarBenjamin I tried nsolve and I get ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance, not on IOTAUSDT but on a different symbol. So nsolve suffers from its own set of optimization problems since selecting an optimization interval seems parameter-dependent hence not straightforward. Due to this and also to the fact that I know this function is not computationally expensive to differentiate analytically, I am leading towards an analytical solution; I would prefer to get this working using solve. Do you have any suggestions to that effect?

@OscarBenjamin also re MRE, most of the examples are to show working parameters for comparison. If you want me to edit the post to exclude those, I can.

There are several problems with posting too much code. If I can read all the (e.g. 4 lines of) code quickly there is a chance I might run it, see what is happening, and then explain what the problem is and show what the fixed code should be. If it's 100 lines then I'm not even going to read it. Also when answering questions I want the answer to be useful to other people who might read it in future but if the question has large amounts of irrelevant code then no one else will understand it even if I do.

Understood and fixed. The code that I left in is needed, since I tried to compute the expression directly using sympy operations and it always ends up working without arriving at it this precise way.

When using SymPy, float numbers are the cause of many headache. Use exact number whenever possible. If you convert your decimal number to rational number, using nsimplify, the solution will be computed immediatly.
Change these lines of code:
expression = Mul(*product_terms)
# ...
print("Solutions:", solutions)

to:
expression = Mul(*product_terms).nsimplify()
# ...
print("Solutions:", solutions[0].n())


I suspect that the problem is actually the fact that solve does this internally by default. Most likely what is needed is to pass rational=False to solve.

Both of your solutions work. It appears that solve does not convert to rationals the same way nsimplify does, since I took the original and your two solutions and all three produce different results. The original errors, Davide's yields 1.47638941897044, and Oscar's yields 1.47638941897043. If both solve and nsimplify convert floats to rationals, why does the former fail when the latter succeeds? Anyway, thank you both for your solutions.
